# No puedo abrir un form mas de una vez desde otro form

Tags: c#, windows-forms

En mi proyecto uso mdiParent, tengo un form abierto con showdialog() y desde este invoco otro form, el problema es que solo me deja hacerlo una vez, es decir lo abro por primera vez, lo cierro luego intento abrirlo de nuevo y no lo hace.
Aqui el código:

```
  private void btnVerDespachos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            FrmConsultarDespacho frm = Application.OpenForms["FrmConsultarDespacho"] as FrmConsultarDespacho;

            if (frm != null)
            {
                frm.CodigoFactura = _NumFact;
                frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                frm.BringToFront();
            }
            else
            {
                FrmConsultarDespacho llamar = new FrmConsultarDespacho();
                llamar.CodigoFactura = _NumFact;
                llamar.MdiParent = FrmPrincipal.pantalla;
                llamar.Show();
                llamar.BringToFront();
            }
            this.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Funciones.MensagedeError(ex.Message);
        }            
    }
```

Comment: Es llamar el form que no te deja abrir de nuevo o es frm ?

Comment: Deberias dar mas información. Cual es tu formulario modal? Que formulario tratas de abrir desde este? Que formulario intentas abrir por segunda vez? Edita tu pregunta y trata de aclarar estos temas

Answer (score 1):

Puede implementar `e.Cancel` en el evento del cierre del formulario "FrmConsultarDespacho", de esta manera puede evitar que la instancia se elimine y pueda seguir utilizándolo:

```
private void FrmConsultarDespacho_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    //Evita el cierre del formulario
    e.Cancel = true;
    this.Hide();
}
```

en el evento de su botón debe mostrar el formulario:

```
  try
  {....
        FrmConsultarDespacho frm....

        if (frm != null)
        {
            frm.CodigoFactura = _NumFact;
            frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            frm.BringToFront();
            frm.Show(); /***Aqui se muestra el formulario***/

        }
        else
        {....
```